# If I delete an Azure VM do I lose the drives?

Tags: azure, virtual-machines

I have an Azure VM with an OS disk and a 1TB data disk.  I am going to delete the VM today but I do not want to lose the disks.  I'm assuming if I delete the VM the disks will still be available to use in the future.  Am I correct in my assumption?

Comment: Why not make a proper backup and remove any uncertainty?

Comment: Why not make a second VM, then delete it and see what happens?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you delete a VM in Azure the disks are not deleted.

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/windows/find-unattached-disks

Answer (score 1):

Nope With new Azure Resource Manager VMs components are independent, so if you delete the VM doesn't delete any other resources are attached to it. For example Managed disks, NICs, Public IPs.